# How to deploy a python docker image to AWS Elastic beanstalk?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I received a python docker image that works perfectly in local. All I need to do is enter `docker-compose up`  to run the app on localhost.

However, this is a completely different story when it comes to deploy it on AWS Elastic beanstalk and I am struggling since many hours to make it works.

Here is the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.6-stretch

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

then I've build the image by entering `docker build .` and I compress the folder.

On AWS I create a "python docker" application and I upload my zip file. AWS deploy my application successfully and the health color is green but when I click on the app URL I get a `internal error` message. I don't see any error in the bundleLogs.

I can't find the solution to deploy my docker image to AWS elastic beanstalk without issues.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy, and there is very good guiding material on AWS:

See [Single Container Docker environments on Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html) and [Single Container Docker configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html)